# Xcode 6.0.1 with iOS 8.1 , can't select iPhone 6+ device

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6, device, simulator

I've got my iPhone 6+ for dev with iOS 8.1.
My application is iOS8 compatible with minimum iOS target version to 7.0.

With Xcode 6.0.1, I can't select the 7.0.x simulator anymore and can't run my app on my device.

Googled it but can't find and answer.

Comment: You're on Yosemite? If so then it doesn't offer the 7.0 simulator. If you want the 7.0 simulator then run the code in XCode 5, which appears to support 7.0, 6.1, 6.0 and 4.3 (odd that it doesn't support 5, but that seems to be a kernel thing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found.

I had to update to Xcode 6.1, because, as Petesh said, Yosemite not supporting 7.0 simulator.